# FSharp-- Shortest Way to Filter Out Nones?

Tags: f#

Let's say i'm working with a list like:

`let items = [ Some(1); None; Some(8); ];;`

What is the shortest means to get only the `Some` values in the list?

`items |> List.filter Option.isSome;;`

Is that the quickest? Does using `Option.isSome` have any drawbacks?

Comment: drawbacks like what? I would do the same (ok maybe I would do `List.choose id items` because I would not care for the `Some` part).

Comment: @CarstenKönig - `List.choose` is definitely the best method - you should make that an answer.

Comment: @CarstenKönig thank you for schooling me! post and i'll mark as answer. that's a sweet solution

Comment: done but I did not want to *school* you ;) ... I started writing and remembered the function in the middle of it ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To get the values of all `Some` instances in a list `items :: a option list` you can use `List.choose`:

```
let values = List.choose id items
```

this will yield `[1; 8]` for your example.